# Pass Stripe fees to the connected account using on_behalf_of

Tags: stripe-payments

On my Stripe connect implementation I have a code pretty similar to this:

```
stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
  amount=30000,
  currency='gbp',
  payment_method_types=['card'],
  on_behalf_of='{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  transfer_data={
    'destination': '{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  },
)
```

From what I understand, Stripe will create a payment on the main account with a transfer destination to the connected account:

```
Amount:         300,00 AUD
Commission:     9,00 AUD
Net:            291,00 AUD
Transfer:
      to:       connected account
      amount:   300,00 AUD           <----- Want this to be 291,00
      fee:      0.00 AUD
```

**Questions**

1. How can I transfer the net amount to the connected account?.
2. Can I somehow retrieve Stripe fees and modify the transfer amount?

Comment: I'd use  `application_fee_amount` and pass as value ( your commission + the calculated stripe fees). But I'm not 100% sure if this can be used like this with your business model.

Comment: You can calculate the fees via the steps in https://support.stripe.com/questions/passing-the-stripe-fee-on-to-customers